# продолжается выполнение функции

Tags: python, python-3.x

почему, когда запускаешь start(), циклит start() stop() start() stop() и т.д.. он же должен останавливаться после выполнения функции stop() ?изучаю как работают циклы

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import time
from math import floor
m = 3
#print(n, type(n), m, type(m))
a = 20
def start():
    while True:
        try:
            n = 3
            print(n, type(n))
            time.sleep(2)
            while n - 1 > 0:
                #print("while",n)
                n -= 1
                if n == 1:
                    print("n", n, type(n))
                    time.sleep(4)
                    stop()

                while True:
                    try:
                        print(n)
                        time.sleep(2)
                        break
                    except:
                        print("except")
                        time.sleep(2)
        except:
            print("1")

def stop():
    try:
        print("stop")
        time.sleep(4)
    except:
        print("except")
```

Comment: А с чего он должен останавливать? у вас только задержки, но никак не завершение, либо выход за предела цикла

Comment: Дополните код так, чтобы он хоть что-то делал. Или исправьте отступы. Данный код не делает ничего.  А вообще да, в приведенном коде ничего не останавливается.

Comment: Если изучаете циклы, так изучайте их. Выкиньте всю бизнес-логику, трижды вложенный while, try-except, и на __минимально воспроизводимом фрагменте__, определите почему работает так, а не иначе. А когда заработает правильно, начинайте наполнение веток и процедур практическим смыслом.

Comment: если правильно понял питон то он выполняет строчку за строчкой последовательно, то есть на стопе должен остановится!?! что является остановкой для цикла?или в функции стоп надо вызвать сис выход или что ещё?

Comment: На какой стопе он должен остановиться? Почему?

Comment: Потому что у тебя while True) бесконечный цикл

Comment: ну ясеньпень))) у него стоп то есть? ))

Answer (score 0):

вот на просторах нашёл

```
def stop():
    print("stop")
    return 0


flag =  1       
while flag:
    flag = stop()
```

Comment: не помогло решение